# URLconnection crash log explaination required

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am getting the below crash log in my iphone code and I am not able to understand what I am doing to wrong or how to fix it.

Your help would really help my app :)

```
0  0x03256c97 in objc_msgSend ()
1  0x000005c3 in ?? ()
2  0x02ae7dd9 in URLConnectionClient::_clientDidFinishLoading ()
3  0x02b5b1aa in URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload ()
4  0x02adbdf0 in URLConnectionClient::processEvents ()
5  0x02adbc7a in MultiplexerSource::perform ()
6  0x030765fa in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
7  0x030758a8 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
8  0x0355c89d in GSEventRunModal ()
9  0x0355c962 in GSEventRun ()
10 0x004c5372 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

Here is the extract from where I start the connection

```
@interface HttpConnection : NSObject {
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest;
    NSURL *nstrUrl;
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    NSURLConnection *urlConnection;
}
@property (retain)NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property (retain)NSURL *nstrUrl;
@property (retain)NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest;

@implementation HttpConnection
    @synthesize receivedData; 
    @synthesize nstrUrl; 
    @synthesize urlRequest;

    NSAutoreleasePool *lpool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  

        nstrUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;  
    urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:nstrUrl cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:TIMEOUT_INTERVAL];
    [urlRequest addValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
    urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if (urlConnection) { 
        self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    } 
    else { 
        NSLog(@"Connection Not Established");
        // inform the user that the download could not be made   
    } 
    [lpool release];
```

and here is how i release the connection object in connectionDidFinishLoading

```
[receivedData release];
receivedData=nil;
[urlConnection release];
urlConnection=nil;
```

Comment: Do you use @synthesize and @property for your variables?

Comment: i have used synthesize as following : @synthesize receivedData;
@synthesize nstrUrl;
@synthesize urlRequest;

Comment: It seems to me that you're over-releasing the HttpConnection instance

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the connectionDidFinishLoading and see if it ever reaches it.

Comment: i have nslogs in the connectionDidFinishLoading and they come always. I have now added logs right before releasing the receivedData and urlConnection

Comment: I have nslogs in connectionDidFinishLoading, so it does come in to the function and does the release there.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like HTTPConnection has a superclass. For example:

@interface HttpConnection : CPObject

I don't know if that would cause your crash or not.

Comment: Sorry I just put the extract.. It has the superclass  : NSObject